# Paypal payments processing on website

Tags: java, paypal, integration

Concerning to this, I'm trying to integrate paypal with a facebook application. Question is, how could I make to process payments without redirecting to paypal. I'd like to avoid paypal Website payment pro or checkouts as far as possible.

Comment: I think they have a SOAP UI you could use. Other than that, I don't think you have any other options for processing with PayPal.

Comment: That could be a good idea. I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro) would be best suited for a Facebook.  Specifically, [Preapproval](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/preapproval-api-operation) and [Pay](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation).

The first time a user sets up your app they will be redirected to PayPal just to approve your application to make payments on their behalf.  From that point on you can trigger payments using that preapproval key and no further redirection/approval is necessary.